# insertion in the same row for all activities

Tags: android, sqlite

i am here to ask for help again, my problem is that in first activity i have values that i insert into database , in the second activity when i try to insert the values it creates a new row, what i want is the values of second activity completes the row of the first activity. And also how could i refer to the last row ??

i don't know how to do it! so, is there any ideas ?

```
 public void updateMENAGE(int id, int a16, int b17, String rm_18_1ts,
        String rm_18_2ts, int c19, int d20, int e21) {

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(col_Type_habitat,a16);
      values.put(col_Statut_occupation ,b17);
      values.put(col_Nombre_ménages_habitant_logement,rm_18_1ts);values.put(col_Nombre_pièces_occupes_ménage,rm_18_2ts);
      values.put(col_Mode_principal_approvisionnement_eau_potable, c19);
      values.put(col_Mode_principal_éclairage,d20);
      values.put(col_Mode_principal_assainissement,e21);

       db.update(MENAGE,values,_id+"="+id, null);
        }
```

public class ActivityDeux  extends Activity {

```
  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
  public void  ajouter(View v) {
        db.open();

        db.updateMENAGE(1,a16,b17,rm_18_1ts,rm_18_2ts,c19,d20,e21);
        db.close();                     
        }
```

Comment: i hope someone help me, i really need to resolve that, thanks

Comment: I am unable to understand your problem. Do you want to capture data across multiple activities and then finally insert that into a table as single row from one of the activity (probably the last one)?

Comment: I agree with @Dragan's answer, you need to update the record you had inserted in first activity.

Comment: so that's the solution, i thought i can insert into database if i make it global for all activities, that's why i spoke about static reference, thanks for concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert new record. You need to update existing record. That is your solution

Comment: so instead of inserting values in the second activity, i should update the existing record created in the first record, thanks i will try it, but there is no other way ?

Comment: thanks, it works , but how should i indicates the last id in the second activity... i update my question.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. I see that you want to save some values from more activity in one row. So your table have only one row?

Comment: the insertion is okey for the first time, but in the second time when i want insert other row, i should indicates in the second activity the update is for the row two. So, every time i start insering the other activities updates the last row.